# Kotlin: Unresolved Reference for variable from instantiated class

Tags: android, class, kotlin, reference, instance

I make an ear training app and want the levels to be customizable. So I have a class with the same function for each of the 12 tones, so imagine setDb, setD, setEb etc.:

```
class MakeLevel(context: Context) {
    fun setC(something: Boolean): Boolean {
        var c = something
        return c
    }
```

I then instantiate the class in my main activity (FullscreenActivity):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen)
    makeLevel = MakeLevel(this)
}
companion object {
    lateinit var makeLevel: MakeLevel
}
```

Then in the fragment where the levels are selected, I do this:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    majpentlevelbutton.setOnClickListener { view ->
        FullscreenActivity.makeLevel.setC(true)
        // [same for setD, setE, setG and setA, and false for all the other notes]
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_levelSelectFragment_to_chromaticFragment)
    }
}
```

Now here comes my problem: I want to access the value of c to determine whether ther sounds and the button for c should be loaded or not, and I can´t find a way to do so. For example, I´d like to use it like this:

```
if (c == true) {
    c_button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
else {
    c_button.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

I´ve tried `c`, `makeLevel.c`, `FullscreenActivity.makeLevel.c` and many more. Every time I get an `Unresolved reference`. So my question is how do I get a reference on the var c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far `c` is only a local variable within the method `setC`.
If you need the value outside of the method you need to define a property:

```
class MakeLevel(context: Context) {
    var c = initValue
    fun setC(something: Boolean){
        c = something
    }
}
```

Now you can access this variable with: `FullscreenActivity.makeLevel.c`

Comment: Note: in this case there's no point to having a `setC` method, you just write `FullscreenActivity.makeLevel.c = whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to access a variable outside of its scope.

```html
class MakeLevel(context: Context) {
    private var c = initValue

    fun setC(something: Boolean){
        c = something
    }

    fun getC(something: Boolean) {
        return c
    }

    if (getC() == true) 
        c_button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    else 
       c_button.visibility = View.GONE
}
```